# Windows phone issue with OpenStreamForReadAsync

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I'm reading an xml file on windows phone 8 as below:

```
 Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder =    
                      Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

 var file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("myxml.xml");
 var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

 XDocument myDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

it doesn't happen always but sometimes the application just get stuck at file.OpenStreamForReadAsync. no exception, no return ... nothing. it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? I am stuck in a similar situation

Comment: @user1917864 nope... :( i took a different approach.